# Apache Beam that uses time as an input

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm looking to create a Beam input that executes every second and just outputs the time as an input. I know I can do a pcollection that is from numbers like this

```
p.apply(Create.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
        .setCoder(VarIntCoder.of())
```

and I could just create a really large array of numbers and window them to be every second, but is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out that this can be done with [GenerateSequence](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/GenerateSequence.html) for bounded or unbounded sets. In order to get 1 data point out per second, I can use the withRate function and if I don't include a "to" then my pcollection will be unbounded.

```
p.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, new Duration(1000)))
```